# Trigger Not Working on Campaign Members From Child Campaigns

Tags: apex, trigger, campaign, campaign-member

So I have this apex trigger I wrote which is working just fine. I am currently experiencing a very weird issue where the Trigger does not work if the Campaign where the campaign members are from has a parent campaign.

My child campaign has the exact same conditions as the parent campaign, including the available options for member statuses but the trigger is not firing at all when I apply updates to its campaign members.

So to be as clear as possible, let's say I have two campaigns. one is the parent of the other:

-ParentCampaign
      -ChildCampaign

So even tho both campaigns have the exact same conditions the trigger does not fire at all for campaign members from the ChildCampaign.

Here is my trigger:

```
trigger MyTrigger on CampaignMember (after insert, before update, after update) {
    ParentChildHandler handler = new ParentChildHandler();
    if (Trigger.isUpdate){
        if(Trigger.isAfter){
           handler.inheritMemberStatus(trigger.new);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The trigger will be fired irrespective of whether its fired from child or parent as long as it is an after insert and before/after update. A good way to verify is to put a *system.debug* in your trigger. You may like to review any specific condition within your handler to see if you have certain conditions, which is not allowing the flow to be executed in case of child campaigns.

Comment: see exceptions for mass campaign status changes: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_ignoring_operations.htm?search_text=triggers

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I'm having similar problem when after insert trigger on CampaignMember is not fired when insert is done by Dataloader.

Answer (score 1):

Trigger will not fire for when there is a mass campaign status changes. Please refer the below link 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_ignoring_operations.htm?search_text=triggers